# How to send a header in puppeteer

Tags: node.js, request, http-headers, puppeteer

i want to send headers in puppeteer but couldn't managed to do it i used This code

```
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headers : MY_header,
    executablePath: "D:\\Desktop\\node_modules\\puppeteer\\.local-chromium\\win64-848005\\chrome-win\\chrome.exe",
    args: ["--proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8888"],

    });
```

but didnt worked i used this also

> https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2627#issuecomment-393407765

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [page.setExtraHTTPHeaders](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagesetextrahttpheadersheaders) API. Something like:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: "D:\\Desktop\\node_modules\\puppeteer\\.local-chromium\\win64-848005\\chrome-win\\chrome.exe",
    args: ["--proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8888"]
});

const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    'some-header': 'some-value'
});

await page.goto('some_url');
```

As the documentation says, these extra headers will be sent with every request this page initiates. If you want to selectively include the header(s), then you should intercept the request and add them conditionally, as explained in the link in the question.